# How to iterate over a dictionary and add items to its values

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, linq-to-entities

I have a dictionary **Dictionary>** which I iterate over its keys and would like to add collection of more items like **SomeKindOfObject** to the value. The AddRange doesn't work - it doesn't change the value of that entry.
See my code (more or less) :

```
Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<SomeObject>> myDictionary = setDictionary(); //Assume that this method populate the dictionary.
IEnumerable<int> keys = myDictionary.Keys;
foreach (int key in keys)
{
  myDictionary[key].ToList().AddRange(getListOfSomeObject()); // getListOfSomeObject returns IEnumerable<SomeObject>  
  //Or even
  myDictionary[key].ToList().concat(getListOfSomeObject()); 

}
```

myDictionary values stays as they are, I would like to use the AddRange method instead of setting the value with the combined list of the original value and the output of the getListOfSomeObject method

Comment: `ToList` returns **a new list**. Modifying it won´t change the original. If you want to update the list, you shouldn´t use `IEnumerable` in the first place, but `ICollection`.

Comment: myDictionary[key] = new IEnumerable based on old

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToList()` will create a new list. If you modify it, the list stored in the `Dictionary` won't be changed. Assign the newly created list again to the `Dictionary`.

```
Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<SomeObject>> myDictionary = setDictionary(); //Assume that this method populate the dictionary.
IEnumerable<int> keys = myDictionary.Keys;
foreach (int key in keys)
{
  var templist = myDictionary[key].ToList();
  templist.AddRange(getListOfSomeObject());
  myDictionary[key] = templist;

}
```

Can you change the type of your dictionary to `Dictionary<int,List<SomeObject>>`? Then you could modify it directly.